# AttributeError: Module 'pip' has no attribute 'logging'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyomo

I'm new to Python and have been trying to install `pyomo` on windows.

I've installed python version 3.7.3

Following pyomo documentation (http://www.pyomo.org/installation), I've installed the module using `pip`:

```
pip install pyomo
```

after I've run

```
pyomo install-extras
```

and I got the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\plugins\extras.py", line 80, in install_extras
>       pip.logger.consumers = []
>    AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'logger'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)
>     File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>     File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pyomo.exe__main__.py", line 9, in 
>     File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\pyomo_main.py", line 92, in main_console_script
>       ans = main()
>     File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\pyomo_main.py", line 82, in main
>       retval = _options.func(_options)
>     File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\plugins\extras.py", line 100, in pyomo_subcommand
>       return install_extras(options.args, quiet=options.quiet)
>     File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\plugins\extras.py", line 83, in install_extras
>       pip.log.consumers = []
>   AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'log'

How can I solve the problem?